# Getting unexpected shape using tensordot

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensor, attention-model

I'm trying to do dot product between two tensors of shape
(2000, 1, 64)
(2000, 30, 64)
When I do tf.tensorbot between these two with the following code

```
test = tf.tensordot(enc_op,tf.transpose(query_with_time_axis),axes=1)
```

I'm getting the output shape as
(2000, 30, 1, 2000)
But I have to get shape as (2000, 30, 1)

I'm doing this for attention mechanism.
Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using,

```
a=tf.transpose(a,perm=[0,2,1])
```

and then,

```
test=tf.matmul(b,a)
```

where `a` is the first tensor and `b` is the 2nd